# Dynamically loading tabs designed with Scene Builder

Tags: tabs, javafx

I am building a JavaFX app containing a few static tabs on a TabPane, and during startup will be dynamically adding different tabs with different content as driven by a configuration as needed.

Note, each dynamic tab could be different from each other and I will need to selectively pick which one of these dynamic tabs I want to instantiate/add.

I am using Scene Builder to design the GUI for the bulk of the app. So far everything for the static tabs works fine. Here's where my challenge starts.

How do I leverage Scene Builder to design the dynamic tabs, and only instantiate those tabs as desired at run time as configuration dictates?

Thanks Al

Answer (score 3):

I would put the content of each tab into its own FXML file. You can load the ones that are always loaded in the "main" FXML file, using [`<fx:include>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements). Then in the `initialize()` method of the controller for the main fxml, read the configuration and load the other fxml files you need.

Something like

Main.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="MainController">
    <center>
        <TabPane fx:id="tabPane">
            <Tab>
               <fx:include source="StaticContent1.fxml"/>
            </Tab>
            <Tab>
               <fx:include source="StaticContent2.fxml"/>
            </Tab>
            <!-- etc -->
        </TabPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

and

MainController.java

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private TabPane tabPane ;

    public void initialize() {
        Configuration config = readConfiguration(); // (pseudocode)
        if (config.shouldLoadTab1()) {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("DynamicTab1.fxml"));
            Tab tab = new Tab("Some title");
            tab.setContent(loader.load());
            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
        }
        // etc 
    }
}
```

The FXML files for each of the tabs (whether "static" or "dynamic") would just contain the content of the tab (not the tab pane, which is already defined in the main fxml file, or the tabs, which (the way I have set it up) are defined either in the main FXML or by the controller). So you would just have something like

StaticContent1.fxml

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com.fxml">
    <!-- nodes... -->
</VBox>
```

Obviously you can use any layout pane you want in place of the `VBox`.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: My post may have not been clear. I have edited it. I've already created the Tab(s) I want to dynamically add during runtime, and the controller. My challenge is to only instantiate what I'm calling 3 static tabs in my FXML at start up. There are already 'n' number of additional Tabs in my FXML that I have designed with SceneBuilder that I do NOT want to be created at started up. As stated above, after the program is running and as I'm parsing my configuration file, I want to pick and choose which one of the dynamic tabs I want to show up on the alredy existing TabPane. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Sorry. Screwed up previous comment.

Comment: Anything defined in the FXML file will be instantiated by the FXML Loader when it is loaded. You should probably put the content of each tab in a separate FXML file. See updated answer.

Comment: This looks like a winner. I tried this earlier but did not know what was the minimum component hierarchy to create standalone Tab FXML files. According to your example I need a 1.) BoarderPane, 2.) TabPane, then the tab? I guess what confused me befoer I thought the TabPane in the dynamic FXML files would conflict with my main TabPane that is already created in my running program. All I want to do is add the additional tabs to the existing TabPane, so you example will work to accomplish this? Correct?  Thanks Al

Comment: You only need one `TabPane`. The other FXML files should just contain the *content* of the tab (not the tab pane, or, the way I have it, the tab itself). I updated the answer to clarify.